# How do I get the current timezone offset (and formatted it properly)?

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset

How would I use javascript to format the computer's timezone offset to this format: 
`<+/-><hourDiff>:<minuteDiff>`, as in `-7:00` (America/Los_Angeles) for example.

Comment: make your life with js dates sane: use moment.js

Comment: how would i use it though? @NelsonTeixeira

Comment: go to moment.js's page: http://momentjs.com/ it has a very simple syntax. It's all described there and it's really easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `getTimezoneOffset` returns a Number representing the time difference between `UTC` and Local Time, in `minutes`

```js
var date = new Date();
var tzOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
var hours = ~~(tzOffset / 60);
var minutes = Math.abs(tzOffset % 60);
alert('Hours: ' + hours + ' Minutes: ' + minutes);
```